# Windows Event when Desktop is available/Startup finished/Explorer loaded

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service

i am looking for an event that signals that a new user has logged in **AND** the desktop is available/loading is successfully.

what i have done, i have a windows service which accapt **SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE** events. (I enabled **SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE** with **SetServiceStatus()**)
The dwEventType from the Callbackfunction can be one of the values specified in the wParam parameter of the **WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE** message. This is to check what has changed (WTS_SESSION_LOGON, WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF,...).

To this point everything worked fine!!

But the **SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE** event comes to **early**. I want to get an event when the user has logged in **AND** the desktop has initialized successfully (or similar)!

What i want to do, is to show an splashscreen for **3** seconds!
When i start my splash-screen process with the **SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE** Event the process ended befor you will see it.

Comment: What is "available"? GetDesktopWindow()? Desktop icons visible? Explorer finished loading taskbar?

Comment: Perhaps add what you want to do when the desktop becomes available as there may be an alternative solution.

Comment: The Windows Shell registers messages to notify clients when certain events happen. Those messages are delivered to windows running in the same desktop as the Shell. You aren't going to receive those messages in a service context. As for the goal you are trying to accomplish: Users generally don't appreciate having the *"Everything is OK!"* alarm bell rang. Splash screens merely produce noise. If you believe that your service is vital to the well-being of users, show a notification when it failed to start instead.

Comment: In the `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` event, when a user logs in, you can use `CreateProcessAsUser()` to run a new process in that user's new session, and then that process can monitor the Shell/messages as needed until the required conditions are met.

Comment: I already use the CreateProcessAsUser, this workes aleady fine, thx! I understand your Idea, but i cant find the right Shell Event/notification which tell me the login process was succesfully. Can you give me please a tip which one i should choose

Answer (score 0):

According to [Receiving Events in a Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/receiving-events-in-a-service), *However, there is no console event sent when an interactive user logs on. For information on receiving notification when a user logs on, see [Creating a Winlogon Notification Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthN/creating-a-winlogon-notification-package).*
You need [**StartShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/winlogon-notification-events) Winlogon Notification Event.